# Detect ajax call, ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

how can I detect if a request is an AJAX-request (from jQuery) on the server-side of a ASP.net application. I don´t want to do this: mypage.aspx?this_is_ajax=true...

ex.

```
$.get("mypage.aspx");
```

On the server side I want to do certain things when the request is a ajax request...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not certain, so I'll post as a comment, but check the IsCallback property of your page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC had a great extension for this, that did work with JQuery.  It checked it this way:

Check the core collection:

```
request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"
```

Check the headers collection (ensuring its not null):

```
request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"
```

It did it as an extension method, so you could recreate it, or use it if you are using ASP.NET MVC through `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`.