# Request.IsAjaxRequest() method not found in MVC4 when using ASPX engine

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't seem to find the IsAjaxRequest() method when creating a partial view using ASPX engine. But it is available when I use Razor.

Is there a work around using this method in ASPX engine?

```
<%
   if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) //compile error because method is not available.
   {
       //do something
   }
%>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441735/detect-ajax-call-asp-net

Comment: Thanks v much. If you can put this in an answer, I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: No problem. Appreciate it, but not really my answer so if you like it, up-vote the original question/answer.